# Greasemonkey script and sorting elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, greasemonkey

I'm doing a small script to add functionality to the facebook find friends page: basically order the suggested friends by mutual friends.

The code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/x6Ss326A

I've tested the script modularly, so I know the paths, sorting function are ok. I've used the same technique to sort items in a odered list with simple text, successfully. The problem is in the behaviour of the sorting method, but I cant figure out what's wrong.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compare function used by sort has to return either a negative number, zero or a positive number, depending on how the arguments should be sorted - not just `true` or `false`. See the [MDN entry on sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description) for reference.

The simplest fix for your problem would be to change the return statement of your `sortFriend` function to

```
return friendsOfB - friendsOfA;
```